# Get Certificate Information from Url Android Programmatically

Tags: android, ios, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Is it possible to get the certificate information from the `Url` ? In iOS, it has `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge`which gives the information if the `url` contains `https`.

The same way do we have any way to get the certificate information for the particular `url` through Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X509TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    for (TrustManager tm : managers) {
                        if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                            ((X509TrustManager) tm).checkClientTrusted(
                                    chain, authType);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    for (X509Certificate cert : chain) {
                        // cert gives the server Certificate Information.
                        if (cert.getIssuerX500Principal().equals(
                                trustedRoot.getIssuerX500Principal())) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    for (TrustManager tm : managers) {
                        if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                            ((X509TrustManager) tm).checkServerTrusted(
                                    chain, authType);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    ArrayList<X509Certificate> issuers = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (TrustManager tm : managers) {
                        if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                            issuers.addAll(Arrays
                                    .asList(((X509TrustManager) tm)
                                            .getAcceptedIssuers()));
                        }
                    }
                    return issuers.toArray(new X509Certificate[issuers
                            .size()]);
                }

            };
```

**Check for this `// cert gives the server Certificate Information.`** **in the above code.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible :

Step1 : enter url in broswer , click on 2 tab as shown below :

[image]

Step 2 : open Detail Tab

Step 3 : Export the public key from there.

[image]

Step 4 : get you .cert file .

Step 5 : generate keystore from .cert file and place that in android

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I need it through code. Can we get this through Code ? @N5.

Comment: atelats you need to get keystore file manually , then you can use that for ssl connection in android, yes progratically u can connect to https but need keystore to be present in code which is generated manually

Comment: the Url, which i need to check is also dynamic. it's not static.. How come i can know that user will be using only this url. Can i get the keystore file dynamically ? @N5.

Comment: not sure of , this is the approch i could actually execute .